# While JBPM spring integration getting org.jbpm.task.Attachment" cannot be resolved error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jbpm, kie

i am new to jbpm. i am trying to run this [github](https://github.com/Nijhazer/jbpm-spring-quickstart/tree/master/src/main/java/com/nijhazer/jbpm/quickstart) application on my eclipse workspace.

i upgraded jbpm version from `5.4.0-Snapshot` to `5.4.0.Final` and getting  errors like:

In [TaskServiceSetup.java](https://github.com/Nijhazer/jbpm-spring-quickstart/blob/2217014bcb6796ea84cf4968f40d94cd30102d60/src/main/java/com/nijhazer/jbpm/quickstart/TaskServiceSetup.java#L43) file transactionManager cannot be resolved to a variable.

and `SyncWSHumanTaskHandler` is deprecated, what is the alternative to this class?

Answer (score 1):

First `transactionManager` is never declared in your class.

Second use `GenericHTWorkItemHandler` instead of the deprecated `SyncWSHumanTaskHandler`